# Unable to update the value of a public object

Tags: java, global-object

my problem is i am not able to update the value of an object array...

The code is :

```
public class GlobalVariable {

    public int noOfSms = 0;
    public CheckingClass object = new CheckingClass ();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       GlobalVariable call = new GlobalVariable ();
       call.driver();
    }

    private void driver() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        object = CheckingFun();

     //   System.out.println("The No Of Sms"+noOfSms);
       System.out.println("Array Value"+object.array[noOfSms] + "     The number value"+object.number);
        }
    }

    private CheckingClass CheckingFun() {

        System.out.println("The No Of Sms "+noOfSms + "\n");
        object.array[noOfSms] = noOfSms;
        object.number = noOfSms;
        noOfSms = noOfSms + 1;

        return object;

    }
```

The other class is :

```
public class CheckingClass {
public int number ; 
public int[] array = new int [5];

}
```

Here object is an object of another class. My problem is in this line

**`object.array[noOfSms] = noOfSms;`**

The output is as follows

```
The No Of Sms 0

Array Value0     The number value0
The No Of Sms 1

Array Value0     The number value1
The No Of Sms 2

Array Value0     The number value2
```

What i don't understand is that why isn't the value of array updated. When the value of number which is also an attribute of the object is updated.

But the output i want is :

```
 Array Value0     The number value0
The No Of Sms 1

Array Value1     The number value1
The No Of Sms 2

Array Value2    The number value2
```

Comment: I would suggest to post some compilable code.

Comment: You do realize that you're updating a different slot in the array each time with `[noOfSms]`, right?

Comment: @Thomas yes i do i want the index of array to be updated each time i come in that function

Comment: before your give me -1 for a bad question ....Kindly answer it so that  i do get something useful after bearing a damage to what little reputation i have !!!!

Comment: Post some compilable code. You posted non compilable code, and an output that doesn't come from the code you posted. How do you want us to discover where the problem is? You also don't say what output you expect. Only the one you get.

Comment: @ JB Nizet  i have edited my question i hope now it helps !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing `array[0]` each time in your output, while each loop is updating `array[0]`. `array[1]`, etc.

Edit:

You're incrementing `noOfSms` at the end of `CheckingFun()`.  So for the first pass, you set `array[0] = 0`, but before you reach your println, `noOfSms` has been incremented and is now 1.  So you print `array[1]`, which has not been initialized.

Comment: I was checking so change it to array[0]... but previously i was doing array[noOfsms] and it still gives me the same output :(

Answer (score 0):

`object.array[0]` You repeatedly calling this function for three times

So array[0] value is 0

```
`object.array[i]`
```

Comment: thx i did figure it out ...:) but the problem was something else !!